# ui-select-choices not scrolling with view and gets cut off

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have tried all possible solutions which is previously answered to this similar problem but still facing the same problem. Please help me out.

```
<td style="width:20%">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <ui-select multiple ng-model="projectPerson.roles" theme="bootstrap"
                               ng-disabled="!projectPerson.editMode"
                               on-remove="personVm.removeRole(projectPerson, $item)"
                               on-select="personVm.selectRole(projectPerson, $item)">
                        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select">
                            {{$item.roleObject.role}}
                        </ui-select-match>
                        <ui-select-choices repeat="role in projectPerson.roleList | filter: $select.search"
                                           style="max-height: 80px">
                            <div ng-bind="role.role"></div>
                        </ui-select-choices>
                    </ui-select>
                </div>
            </td>
```

Comment: Your form is in table's row. Can you try putting z-index to pull it forward.

Comment: Just for record accept the answer in case I helped you.

Comment: It didn't help @Lokesh

Comment: Can you include your updated code ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ui-select-choices` is there, since it's in `<td>` element, I guess it's hiding behind `<td>`. Put the `z-index` value to high number to bring it forward. Try this code and lemme know if it's working or not

```html
<td style="width:20%">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <ui-select multiple ng-model="projectPerson.roles" theme="bootstrap"
                               ng-disabled="!projectPerson.editMode"
                               on-remove="personVm.removeRole(projectPerson, $item)"
                               on-select="personVm.selectRole(projectPerson, $item)">
                        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select">
                            {{$item.roleObject.role}}
                        </ui-select-match>
                        <ui-select-choices repeat="role in projectPerson.roleList | filter: $select.search"
                                           style="max-height: 80px;z-index:100000">
                            <div ng-bind="role.role"></div>
                        </ui-select-choices>
                    </ui-select>
                </div>
            </td>
```